# Center a JPanel in a JFrame

Tags: swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

How can I put my JPanel in the center of a JFrame without using a layout manager? I want it to be generic for all screen resolutions of course.

Thanks,
Tomer

Comment: I think its a very simple procedure. But I will be happy if anyone will tell me how can I center a JPanel in a JFrame, with or without layout managers. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you don't use layouts (`setLayout(null)`), you need to  calculate the location of the `JPanel` inside the `JFrame`, like:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class a extends JFrame {

public a()
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(200, 200);
    panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    setSize(400, 400); // JFrame arbitrary size.
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
    // Caculate panel location after showing the JFrame in order to get the right insets (window's title bar).
    int panelX = (getWidth() - panel.getWidth() - getInsets().left - getInsets().right) / 2;
    int panelY = ((getHeight() - panel.getHeight() - getInsets().top - getInsets().bottom) / 2);
    panel.setLocation(panelX, panelY);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new a();
}
}
```

Comment: `getContentPane().setLayout(null);`  This Q&A was cited in another question at SO.  For the record, a `null` layout is not the way to go here.  It is rarely, if **ever** the right way to go.