# Adding multiple types of Backgrounds to one JFrame

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe

My title is a bit confusing, so I'll try to explain. What I'd like to do is have a background image in my application that stays static in the top center (as in, center on the x axis, and right at the top from the y axis). And I want this even when the JFrame is re-sized. However, underneath that image, I would like a pattern I made to be repeated enough to fit the window size.

I thought of several ways to do this (and used StackOverflow questions that have already been answered) to come up with a logical solution. (I say logical because it doesn't actually work.)

I would use this -

```
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.getContentPane(backgroundImage);
  panel.setSize(400, 400); // JFrame arbitrary size.
  panel.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
  panel.setVisible(true);

  int panelX = (panel.getWidth() - panel.getWidth() - panel.getInsets().left - panel.getInsets().right) / 2;
  panel.setLocation(panelX, 0);
```

Which is based off of the solution from this - [Center a JPanel in a JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855605/center-a-jpanel-in-a-jframe)

The problem I have with this code is that I get an error when I try to use the getContentPane();
(The error is "The method getContentPane() is undefined for the type JPanel".)

And underneath that JPanel, I would have ANOTHER JPanel with the following code -

```
BufferedImage titledImageFile = ImageIO.read(new File(IMAGE_PATH_TILED));
TiledImage test = new TiledImage(tiledImageFile);

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
int width = getWidth();
int height = getHeight();
int imageW = tileImage.getWidth(this);
int imageH = tileImage.getHeight(this);

// Tile the image to fill our area.
for (int x = 0; x < width; x += imageW) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y += imageH) {
        g.drawImage(tileImage, x, y, this);
    }
}
}
```

Hopefully my question is clear;
Am I going about this the correct way, or is there something else I should do? Additionally, how do I get the JFrame to work with this?

And finally, if this question is downvoted, please leave an explanation so I can fix/prevent it from happening in the future.

Comment: 1) *"Which is based off of the solution from this - Center a JPanel in a JFrame"*  I just reviewed that Q&A & down-voted the accepted answer on the basis of using a `null` layout.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) for the best way to center a component.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (like the linked example).

Comment: 1). For that, I understand what you mean, I'll use the BorderLayout method. 
2). Trying to get a Self-Contained example will be hellish how I set up my project... Hopefully I meet the other requirements.

Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 1):

You to need to built each panel up on top of each other

Start with your `JFrame`, using a `BorderLayout`, add you `TitledPane` to it.  This will allow the titled pane to occupy the entire space of the frame.

Set the layout for the `TitledPane` to `GridBagLayout`.  Using the following constraints, add a `JLabel`, whose icon property has been set to your image...

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
```

It would, also, be faster if you cached the result of titling to a separate `BufferedImage`.  You would need to update it each time the panel was `invalidated`, but it would provide a faster repaint...

Comment: Thanks for the help! The problem I'm having is that I already have an object set to NORTH for my JFrame (an image) BoderLayout, and all of the information is in the CENTER of the BorderLayout. How would I use what you described without messing this up / pushing all of the data to the very botton of the page?

Comment: So, add another panel to CENTER position add the remaining omponents to it instead, as described